# sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: data1 (Sqlite code 1):

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I've searched the internet for this problem but couldn't get any working response.
I believe it's from the selection but I don't know what is wrong with it.

I get this error :
        `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: data1 (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: SELECT sort_key, photo_uri ...`

after executing this code to retrieve the phone contacts:

```
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String no07 = "%07";
    String no407 = "%+407";

    String selection = "((" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " NOTNULL) AND ("
            + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " != '' ) AND (("
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " LIKE '" + no07 + "' ) OR ("
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " LIKE '" + no407 + "' )))";

    Cursor phones = getActivity()
            .getContentResolver()
            .query(uri, null, selection, null, null);
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try debugging/logging your entire select statement. My guess is that you are making a column selection that is not present in the table being queried.

Comment: I've been having this problem only after adding the LIKE rows

Comment: If you really need the LIKE rows, that is ok. But it would really help if you will log the entire select statement. You can then run that select statement manually on the DB server and then you will see where the error is. Edit your question and post the select statement log.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really know how to log and run the select statement manually on the DB

Comment: [This](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html) will help you how to debug.

Comment: But how to run the select statement manully? if I set the debug checkpoint on the select row it will crash the app when pressing Step Over. Sorry if I don't understand as I should

Comment: Debug it before the selection call. Put the breakpoint just above the line before you execute the select statement. OR alternatively you can log the select statement before executing it. Ex. Log.Debug("Your Activity", "Select statement : " + selection);

Answer (score 1):

According to your error there is no such a column `data1` from the URI you are querying. The `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER` column included in your `selection` should be causing the exception.
You might want to query a different table from the ContactsContract which is `ContactsContract.Data` that as stated at [the overview from the ContactsContract](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html)

> A row in the ContactsContract.Data table can store any kind of personal data, such as a phone number or email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

### Change Your Query URI.

You are using a URI that is not meant for searching/filtering Contacts and does not have access to those columns:

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
```

You need to use a URI that has access to the columns you're trying to filter on, like this:

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
```

There's a decent breakdown of what URIs to use and when on the [Android SDK Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts):

> - If you need to read an individual contact, consider using CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI instead of CONTENT_URI.
> - If you need to look up a contact by the phone number, use PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, which is optimized for this purpose.
> - If you need to look up a contact by partial name, e.g. to produce filter-as-you-type suggestions, use the CONTENT_FILTER_URI URI.
> - If you need to look up a contact by some data element like email address, nickname, etc, use a query against the ContactsContract.Data table. The result will contain contact ID, name etc.